# Vuex state is getting undefined when called in an action method

Tags: vuex

I am trying to get vuex state variable in an action method.I use `async` action method.

It always return undefined. But when I checked in vuex store in dev tools the variable has a value actually.

Here is action method:

```
async getSubCategories({ commit,state }) {
        var result = await categoriesService.getSubCategories(state.selectedCategory.id)
        commit('getSubCategories',result);
    },
```

Actually `state.selectedCategory` has a state value. But it is getting as undefined.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me what is and what is not undefined. The return value of your action is undefined because you don't return anything (except a promise since it's async). `state.selectedCategory` cannot be undefined otherwise you would get a "cannot get property 'id' or undefined". So as I understand it, `result` is undefined, but to help you we need to know what `categoriesService.getSubCategories` is.

Comment: It is vuex @seblor. service method is returning a collection of data. There is no problem with the service. Undefined is state.selectedCategory.

Comment: Then just to be sure, are you getting the error "cannot get property 'id' of undefined" ?

Comment: Because state is getting undefined. Also id is getting undefined. Main problem is state

Comment: If `state` or `selectedCategory` is undefined, you would have a runtime error. I'm sorry, but as it is, I am not able to help you. If you can please include a minimal reproducible example in your question.

Comment: I think it is common problem. It is because awaitable async operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with calling async actions by correct order.

The order should be like this in a component:

```
  await this.getCategories();
  await this.setSelectedCategory();
  await this.getSubCategories()
```

Because of there is no `selectedCategory` it is causing an error for `selectedCategory` as `undefined`.